# Is the function $h:[-4,0]\rightarrow{[0,4]}$ defined by $h(x)=\sqrt{16-x^{2}}$ invertible or not?

Tags: functions

Determine if $h:[-4,0]\rightarrow{[0,4]}$ defined by $h(x)=\sqrt{16-x^{2}}$  is invertible.

To determine if the function $h$ is invertible or not, I should show if it is one-to-one and onto.

I knew that $h$ is one-to-one, i.e. $\sqrt{16-x^{2}},-4\leq{x}\leq{0}$, because it is just one-fourth of a circle with radius 4 located at Quadrant II. Thus, it will pass the horizontal line test because no horizontal line will intersect it more than once. Therefore $h$ is one-to-one.

However, I found it difficult to show that $h$ is onto. And, can I improve my answer on showing $h$ is one-to-one?

Comment: What is the definition of "onto"?

Answer (score 1):

This function $f:[-4,0] \rightarrow [0,4]$ is a bijection (one-to-one and onto). So the inverse exists
$$f^{-1}:[0,4]\rightarrow [-4,0], f^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{16-x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

At first, the image of $h$ is in nonnegative region of the real line.

Then, you can see that you can choose some $x \in [-4, 0]$ to satisfy $0 \le c=h(x) \le 4$ for any $c$. Explicitly, this is $x =-\sqrt{16-c^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the definitions, suppose there exist $x$ and $y$ in $[-4,0]$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ then $\sqrt{16-x^2}=\sqrt{16-y^2}$

$\implies x^2=y^2 \implies x=y$ (since they are both negative).

Now is it onto?

Let $y\in [0,4]$ is there $x\in [-4,0]$ such that $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$?

Yes there is, take $x=\sqrt{16-y^2}$

So it is a bijection.